# parsing irregular data table in R

Tags: r, parsing, csv, for-loop

I'm new to R, and so it's possible I haven't hit the right search term, so would love any direction.

I need to parse a highly irregular, extremely large .csv. A single column contains 10 categories of categorical data, followed by 14 columns which may contain one or more values for a numeric record. This .csv was hand-formatted to look like a pivot table, and so there are a varying number of rows between each of my records. There are a lot of irregularities in how this data was entered. This is just a tiny fragment.

```
Categories       x1      x2       x3

12123           222.0   206.7   236.7
Novartis Seeds  222.0       
N67-T4          220.8       
4/19/2000       220.8       
32000           220.8       
Soybean         220.8       
Y               220.8       
No-Till         220.8       
N7070BT         223.2       
4/19/2000       223.2       
32000           223.2       
Soybeans        223.2       
Y               223.2       
No-Till         223.2       
Syngenta               206.7    236.7
N68-K7                          236.7
4/24/2002                       236.7
36500                           236.7
Soybeans                        236.7
Y                               236.7
No-Till                         236.7
NX7210                 206.7    
5/8/2001               206.7    
38000                  206.7    
Corn                   206.7    
Y                      206.7    
No-Till                 206.7
```

I think I've come up with a system, for (though I'm reading row by row, which I've seen mentioned is the least efficient way to code in R):

```
      #yc is my data table.
    #This function was designed to identify character strings in the only category of data (tillage record)
    #which would be consistantly associated with a single record (yield). I create a new column of 0's and 1's, where
    #1's are associated with a single record
    tillTFfn<-function(yc){
    yc$tillTF<-rep(NA, length(yc$Categories))
                             for (i in 1:length(yc$Categories))
                               if (grepl("till", yc$Categories[i], ignore.case=TRUE)==TRUE){
                                 yc$tillTF[i]<-1
                               } else if (grepl(" Minimum-Till ", yc$Categories[i], ignore.case=TRUE)==TRUE){
                                 yc$tillTF[i]<-1
                               } else if (grepl("Conv", yc$Categories[i], ignore.case=TRUE)==TRUE){
                                 yc$tillTF[i]<-1
                               } else if (grepl("Not", yc$Categories[i], ignore.case=TRUE)==TRUE){
                                 yc$tillTF[i]<-1
                               } else {
                                 yc$tillTF[i]<-0}


                             return(yc)
    }
    YC<-tillTFfn(yc)
    #I then create another new column with the sum of all records reported in each row. Values in "colsum" which coincide with
    #"tillTF" are my record
    YC$colsums<-rowSums(YC[,2:16], na.rm=TRUE)
    #now I'm attempting to create a function that reads YC row by row, and returns a row value with each categorical variable
    array<-rep(0, length(12))
    #The assumption here is that the first 10 rows of column 1 will contain a single value of each category
    for (i in 1:12))
      if(YC$tillTF[i]==1){
        array1[12]<-(YC$colsums[i])
        array1[11]<-(YC$Categories[i])
        array1[10]<-(YC$Categories[i-1])
        array1[9]<-(YC$Categories[i-2])
        array1[8]<-(YC$Categories[i-3])
        array1[7]<-(YC$Categories[i-4])
        array1[6]<-(YC$Categories[i-5])
        array1[5]<-(YC$Categories[i-6])
        array1[4]<-(YC$Categories[i-7])
        array1[3]<-(YC$Categories[i-8])
        array1[2]<-(YC$Categories[i-9])
        array1[1]<-(YC$Categories[i-10])
      }
    #This is my imaginary way to create a data table where the array created above is the first row of a new data table YC_NT
    YC_NT<-rbind(array)

    #This is my imaginary function for the remainder of YC. The idea is that the loop will run through each row of YC, stop
    #when YC$tillTF = 1, rewrite values of the array by reading back up through the column until YC$tillTF=1 again, and then print 
    #that array magically as a row on the new data table YC_NT
    for (i in 13:length(YC$tillTF))
      if (YC$tillTF[i]=1)
        array[12]<-(YC$colsums[i])
        array[11]<-(YC$Categories[i])
        if (YC$tillTF[i-1]==0)
          array[10]<-YC$Categories[i-1]
                else 
                  rbind(array, YC_NT)
        if (YC$tillTF[i-2]==0)
          array[9]<-YC$Categories[i-2]
              else
                rbind(array, YC_NT)
        if(YC$tillTF[i-3]==0)
          array[8]<-YC$Categories[i-3]
              else
                rbind(array, YC_NT)
        if(YC$tillTF[i-4]==0)
          array[7]<-YC$Categories[i-4]
              else
                rbind(array, YC_NT)
        if(YC$tillTFF[i-5]==0)
          array[6]<-YC$Categories[i-5]
              else
                rbind(array, YC_NT)
        if(YC$tillTFF[i-6]==0)
          array[5]<-YC$Categories[i-6]
              else
                rbind(array, YC_NT)
        if(YC$tillTFF[i-7]==0)
          array[4]<-YC$Categories[i-7]
              else
                rbind(array, YC_NT)
        if(YC$tillTFF[i-8]==0)
          array[3]<-YC$Categories[i-8]
              else
                rbind(array, YC_NT)
        if(YC$tillTFF[i-9]==0)
          array[2]<-YC$Categories[i-8]
              else
                rbind(array, YC_NT)
    else 
      array<-array
    return(YC_NT)

#I recognize that my parenthesis and brackets aren't in yet, and once again that this is not how rbind() works.
```

1) Can I do nested conditional statements in R, like I've done here?
2) Is there a function that I can use to print a vector as a row to a data table without first naming that individual vector and typing it into rbind (apply() doesn't seem to be working)

Comment: What you show looks like fixed width data. If that is the case, use `read.fwf` to import it. However, it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It might be better to clearly describe the input data structure and show a bit of the output you desire. I'm not sure simply trying to fix the code you've written is the best way to go about it (especially if it's not currently run-able).

Comment: thanks! I've re-written my question with your advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122131/parsing-data-in-r-alternative-to-rbind-which-can-be-put-in-for-lopp-to-writ